# "pointer-event: none" not being respected when "margin: auto" used

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage where I want my content to be center aligned on the page and whenever the user hovers over the page outside of the content I would like the pages background to change color.  If I move over the `.content` `div` and back to the `.background` `div` it should change the `.background` `div` color again.

In the below code, it works great if you move you mouse off the bottom or top of the `content` `div`.  If you move the mouse left or right off the `content` `div` the `mouseover` event listener is not fired.  It looks like it could be a bug with the browser's implementation of `pointer-events` or maybe I am doing something wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
function changeColor(event) {
    event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = ('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
}
var el = document.querySelector(".background");
el.addEventListener("mouseover", changeColor, false);
el.addEventListener("click", changeColor, false);
```

```css
.content {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.content > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: grey;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.background {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    background: green
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div>
        <p>Proin hendrerit ullamcorper justo in facilisis. Nullam id efficitur neque, id iaculis enim. Duis imperdiet nisl sed vulputate interdum. Vivamus hendrerit nisi dolor, sit amet pellentesque risus vulputate nec. Proin finibus quam iaculis varius egestas. Nunc volutpat mauris at dolor venenatis semper. Phasellus quis vestibulum ante. In ac dolor placerat, dapibus nulla ut, ultrices lorem. Ut elementum ex quis ligula blandit, eu mollis ipsum porta. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras scelerisque, metus ac hendrerit hendrerit, mauris ex cursus neque, in placerat neque risus congue risus. Proin tincidunt, purus efficitur tempor tempus, nisi ex posuere ante, sit amet suscipit quam nisl non risus. Praesent viverra quam viverra arcu faucibus suscipit.</p>               
    </div>
</div>
<div class="background">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `.content` div is automatically a block element, the content reaches over the whole line (100%) on the left and right on `mouseover`:

[image]

```js
function changeColor(event) {
    event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = ('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
}
var el = document.querySelector(".background");
el.addEventListener("mouseover", changeColor, false);
el.addEventListener("click", changeColor, false);
```

```css
body {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.content>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.background {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  background: green;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div>
        <p>Proin hendrerit ullamcorper justo in facilisis. Nullam id efficitur neque, id iaculis enim. Duis imperdiet nisl sed vulputate interdum. Vivamus hendrerit nisi dolor, sit amet pellentesque risus vulputate nec. Proin finibus quam iaculis varius egestas. Nunc volutpat mauris at dolor venenatis semper. Phasellus quis vestibulum ante. In ac dolor placerat, dapibus nulla ut, ultrices lorem. Ut elementum ex quis ligula blandit, eu mollis ipsum porta. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras scelerisque, metus ac hendrerit hendrerit, mauris ex cursus neque, in placerat neque risus congue risus. Proin tincidunt, purus efficitur tempor tempus, nisi ex posuere ante, sit amet suscipit quam nisl non risus. Praesent viverra quam viverra arcu faucibus suscipit.</p>               
    </div>
</div>
<div class="background">
</div>
```

Comment: My example is a simplistic version.  I still need the `background` `div` because my content will be embedded in part of another page, so I don't have access or want to directly change the color of the `body` tag.

Comment: But am I correct in the functionality, meaning that you want it to also change if you move over the text box and back to the `.body`?

Comment: Yes, that its what I want

Comment: I understood (with the help of your updated explanation). I updated my answer with the correct solution. :)

Comment: @Eric If the answer helped you, can you please mark it as the accepted answer? If you still have any issues, feel free to ask more.

Comment: I noticed that when you changed it to `inline` with width of 300px on the `.content` is no longer respected.  Is there an additional fix for this?

Comment: At the bottom of my answer I gave a possible solution for that. It's not ideal, though. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple to explain. 
Have a look at my screenshot. The padding of the `body` tag overlays over the `.background`.
If you try it inside the colored container but outside the padding area it works.

EDIT: And as the padding still belongs to the `body` and you do actually not "mouseover" the `.background` the event is not fired.

[image]

Comment: Adding the `pointer-events: none;` to the `content` `div` should make the padding not block the mouse event. Do you know why this is not working?